# Decrement with setInterval in for loop

Tags: javascript

Using this construction of code, how to decrement as a stopwatch the inserted  number of the the user with an interval of 1 second. I have created this script but i don't get the necessary result. Which is the issue of the code?

```js
  var seconds = prompt();
    setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = seconds; i>0; i--){
            console.log(i)
        }
    },1000);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: It does work properly for me, it prints `seconds` numbers on the console (seconds .. 1) each second.

Comment: (remember to describe what behavior you want, instead of just the code)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function which checks the value and exits the timer interval.

It works in two parts, first set an interval and then clear the interval.

Inside of the callback show the value and decrement it. Then check if the value is smaller than zero and clear the interval in this case.

You do not need a `for` loop inside of the callback, because you want to display only one value.

```js
var seconds = +prompt(),
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = seconds;
        if (--seconds < 0) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: using my code, without function, it is posible to get the same result?

Comment: @Asking "without function"? Your code _does_ have a function.

Comment: ^^ i think without a named function. just move the function insides of `setInterval` as first parameter-

Answer (score 0):

set value : document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = seconds;

and then end by  clearInterval(stopWatch);

```
<script>
    var seconds = prompt();

    var stopWatch = setInterval(function() { 
    if(seconds <=0){
        clearInterval(stopWatch);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = seconds;
    seconds--;
}, 1000);
```

```
 <p id="result"></p>
```